# Analogues of Primitive Recursive Functions

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, ordinal-computability

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an admissible set (possibly with urelements). I am wondering if there is some good notion of "primitive recursive arithmetic" relative to $\mathbf{A}$. More precisely, I would like to single out a class of $\Pi_{2}$-sentences (with parameters) about $\mathbf{A}$ which reduces to the class of $\Pi_{2}$-theorems of PRA when specialized to the case where $\mathbf{A}$ is the set of hereditarily finite sets. In particular, I would like to single out a special class of "provably total" $\Sigma_1$-definable functions on $\mathbf{A}$, which reduces to the class of primitive recursive functions when $\mathbf{A} =$ hereditarily finite sets.

I would be grateful for any pointers to relevant literature. If it helps, I am primarily interested in the case where $\mathbf{A}$ is the smallest admissible set containing some mathematical structure $M$ (that is, $\mathbf{A} = HYP_M$, in the notation of Barwise's book).

Comment: Moschovakis' book "Elementary induction on abstract structures" develops recursion theory on admissible sets. In the book he proves the Barwise Gandy Moschovakis theorem which says that if $A$ is a transitive set closed under pairing then the inductive relations on the structure $(A,\epsilon)$ are exactly the relations on $A$ which are $\Sigma_1$ over an admissible set. I don't know if this is directly relevant to your question, or if the theory reduces to PRA on $A$ if $A=H_{\omega}$. (see chapter 9 of the book).

Comment: When I read this I am reminded of Fenstad and Abstract Recursion Theory.  I don't quite know why; it may not fit in with your  program.

Comment: Jensen and Karp's primitive recursive set functions give your generalized functions, and Michael Rathjen, A proof-theoretic characterization of the primitive recursive set functions, JSL 57(3), 1992 (http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/PrimRec.pdf) seems to give the theory that you want.

Comment: @Carlo It is relevant, but I am asking for something more refined: I want to consider not just which sets are $\Sigma_1$-definable in $A$, but when $A$ "knows" that one $\Sigma_1$-set is contained in another.

Comment: @Ulrik That paper looks quite relevant, but not exactly what I'm looking for. If I'm reading it right, it seems to be about functions whose totality is provable using very weak set-theoretic assumptions, analogous to the characterization of primitive recursive functions as those functions which are provably total using very weak arithmetic assumptions. But I'm hoping for something which is specific to a fixed admissible set $A$, and specializes to primitive recursive arithmetic when I take $A = HF$. (Something that would generalize PRA, rather than being analogous to PRA.)

Comment: @JacobLurie:  Considering your comment to Ulrik,I would like to know why you are asking the question--what is its motivation? Also, when you use the term $A$=$HYP_{M}$, are you meaning $\mathbb HYP$($\mathbb A_{\mathfrak M}$) as used in chapter IV, def 1.4 of $Admissible$ $Sets$ $and$ $Structures$?

Answer (score 2):

(This is more of a comment than an answer, but it's a bit too long to be split into comments so I'll post it as an answer.)

I don't know about functions defined on an arbitrary admissible set, but at least for admissible levels of the constructible hierarchy, you might be interested in what are called "$(\infty,0)$-recursive functions" in chapter VIII ("Recursion on Ordinals") of Peter G. Hinman's book *Recursion-Theoretic Hierarchies* (1978, [available here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235415519)), and also on [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108949/various-definitions-of-recursion-from-ordinal-machines) I asked a while ago while trying to make sense (without much success) of the various definitions.  Hinman writes (op.cit., p.378) that:

> The $(\infty,0)$-recursive functions will play somewhat the role here of the primitive recursive functions of ordinary recursion theory.

Perhaps even more relevant to your question would be the $(\infty,\lambda)$-recursive functions in Hinman's terminology, or even more the *primitive* $(\infty,\lambda)$-recursive functions in the terminology of the question I linked to, where $\lambda$ is the height of the admissible set considered (at least for a $L_\lambda$).  But as I noted, the precise relation between these concepts escapes me.

Also somewhat relevant to your question might be Stephen G. Simpson's paper titled "Short Course on Admissible Recursion Theory" on p. 355–390 of Fenstad, Gandy & Sacks (eds.), *Generalized Recursion Theory II* (1978), proceedings of a symposium held in Oslo in 1977.  It contains the clearest (if terse) explanation I found so far of how primitive recursive ordinal functions are defined and how they relate to more general recursion on ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for the case $\mathbb A$=$\mathbb H$$Y$$P_{\mathfrak M}$ (which seems, if I am understanding your question correctly, what you are referring to), since $\mathbb H$$F_{\mathfrak M}$$\subseteq$$\mathbb H$$Y$$P_{\mathfrak M}$, the generalization of primitive recursive function you get (rather than want, possibly) are the primitive computable functions of Moschovakis which are defined in his papers "Abstract First-Order Computability, I" and "Abstract First-Order computability,  II".  In fact, Thm. 2.6 in Chapter II of Barwise's book states that the $\Sigma_1$ relations on $\mathbb H$$F_{\mathfrak M}$ are semi-search computable on $\mathfrak M$ and the $\Delta_1$ relations on $\mathbb H$$F_{\mathfrak M}$ are the search-computable relations on $\mathfrak M$ (the search-computable relations being Moschovakis' generalization of the general recursive functions on $\mathfrak N$=(N,+,$\cdot$)) so what you seem to require, that is,  that there exists a special class of "provably total" $\Sigma_1$ functions on $\mathbb A$ which reduces to the class of primitive recursive functions when $\mathbb A$=$\mathbb H$$F_{\mathfrak M}$ does not exist.  That is why I asked those particular questions in my comment to you.  If you believe my observation is incorrect, please be so kind as to show me how the class of functions you are interested in can exist.

Comment: I'm a little confused - what do you mean by " . . . the generalization of primitive recursive function you get . . ."? Get according to what process? Also, how do you get from Barwise' result to the statement that no such class exists? (I'm probably just missing something, but this isn't clear to me.)

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't follow either. What exactly are you saying you can rule out?

Comment: @NoahS:  If this helps any, the primitive, prime, and search computable functions of Moschovakis are defined over arbitrary first-order structures $\mathfrak M$ and are the analogues of the primitive recursive functions and general recursive functions over $\mathfrak N$=(N,+,$\cdot$).  Prof. Lurie, in the second paragraph of his question, was interested in the admissible set $\mathbb A$=$\mathbb H$$Y$$P_{\mathfrak M}$  By the theorem I mentioned, the 'primitive recursive' functions over $\mathbb H$$F_{\mathfrak M}$ are the primitive computable functions of Moschovakis,

Comment: (cont.) not the primitive recursive functions over $\mathfrak N$=(N,+,$\cdot$).

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. It seems quite easy to define *some* theory $T_\mathbb{A}$ satisfied by $\mathbb{A}$ and *some* class of functions $F_\mathbb{A}$ on $\mathbb{A}$ such that (1) $T_\mathbb{A}$ prove sthat each $f\in F_\mathbb{A}$ is total and (2) $F_{HF}=PrimRec$. The question is whether there is a reasonably natural choice of such $T$ and $F$. When you bring up Moschovakis it seems you are homing on on specifically one approach, and then arguing that, if we follow that approach, no such class of functions exists (although even here I don't follow your reasoning);

Comment: (cont'd) to me, though, that seems strong evidence (if true) that *that's the wrong approach*. That's why I asked: "get according to what process?" It seems you have some fixed picture of how this generalization should occur, but that picture isn't clear to me.

Comment: @NoahS:  The 'process' is abstracting the notion of general recursive function from $\mathfrak N$= (N,+, $\cdot$) to arbitrary (unordered) first-order structures $\mathfrak U$, primarily as a tool for hierarchy theory.  What puzzles me is why Prof. Lurie, who wrote an 800+ page monograph on higher topos theory, would be even asking a question about admissible sets.  Why?  Because Marie-France Thibault, in the Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra (Vol. 24, 1982, pp 79-83) wrote a paper titled "Pre-Recursive Categories" in which she studies "the free 'cartesian closed category [here is the

Comment: (cont.) tie-in to topos theory--my comment] with a natural number object (in the sense of the Peano-Lawvere Axiom)' generated by the empty category.  In this category, every morphism 1$\rightarrow$$\mathbb N$ represents a natural number and every morphism $\mathbb N$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb N$ represents a function.  Furthermore, the set of functions represented by the morphisms of this category contains strictly [but does not characterize (see Thm. 2.3 and Corollary 2.4)]the primitive recursive functions...[this from her abstract]." Is it possible to characterize the primitive recursive

Comment: (cont.) functions by means of categories?  If so, then (at least for first-order structures $\mathfrak U$) the morphisms will be the primitive computable functions of Moschovakis.  Since the class $V_{KP(U)}$ for the structure ($V_{KP(U)}$,$\in$) is a first-order structure, the primitive computable functions should hold on $V_{KP(U)}$ and the elements of $V_{KP(U)}$ generated by the primitive computable functions and the subclass closed under them via the composition operation $\circ$ should form a category.  One should then be able to use category-theoretic methods to answer Prof. Lurie's

Comment: (cont.) question but Prof. Lurie did not take this route.  That is why I asked what motivated his question.  Have you any idea?  Please let me know.

Comment: @NoahS:  By the way, have you any reasonably natural choice for $T_{\mathbb A}$ and $F_{\mathbb A}$ for $\mathbb A$ admissible satisfying the criteria you mentioned in your comment?  I would be interested in knowing what it is.