# Languages beyond enumerable

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory, teaching

A *language* is a set of finite-length strings from some finite alphabet $\Sigma$.
It is no loss of generality (for my purposes) to take $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$; so a language is a set of bit-strings.

Languages are commonly classified in a hierarchy, with the

- enumerable $\equiv$ recursively enumerable $\equiv$ Turing-recognizable

the outermost set, beyond decidability:

---

[image]

     
<sup>(Figure from [Sipser](https://math.mit.edu/~sipser/).)</sup>

---

My question is about the terminology extending this hierarchy.
The non-enumerable are clearly outside the enumerable ($\equiv$ Turing-recognizable).
But some languages $L$ are enumerable but their complement $\overline{L}$
is not enumerable (such as the language of all Turing Machines that halt
on a given input),
whereas other languages $L$ are not enumerable, and their complement 
$\overline{L}$ is also not enumerable (such as the pairs of "equivalent" Turing machines).

> ***Q1***. Are there standard names for languages that go farther outside of
>   the above diagram?

The set of all languages is uncountable, so there is plenty of room for expanding
the diagram. But I haven't seen a clear, "standard" expansion.

I am seeking a progression further and further out into the uncountable to
help students (and me!) see the vastness.
I am seeking the equivalent of this
iconic complexity-theory hierarchy:

---

[image]

     
<sup>(Image from [Seneca ICT](https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~gpu621/pages/content/intro.html).)</sup>

---

> ***Q2***. Is there an equivalent diagram in language theory?

Comment: "I am seeking a progression further and further out into the uncountable" Note that any class of languages defined in terms of variants of Turing machines that do such-and-such is only going to be countable, since there are only countably many Turing machines.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, for starters there is the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), where enumerable = $\Sigma^0_1$ and it continues $\Pi^0_1$, $\Delta^0_2$, $\Sigma^0_2$ etc.

See also the [Computability Menagerie](http://zoo.ludovicpatey.com/).

[image]

Comment: That's an amazing diagram!

Answer (score 11):

In [my answer to a question about degrees of irrationality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53754/19460), I had posted the following summary account of degrees of complexity, which in the end I believe ultimately reaches into the realm of the upper hierarchies of vastness to which you seem to aspire.

> Answer to [Are some numbers more irrational than others?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53754/19460)
>
> The other answers and comments are fascinating, particularly about the irrationality measure, but allow me to give a little more information along the lines
>   of Mark Sapir's answer by mentioning that there are several
>   very large, intensely studied hierarchies of complexity for
>   reals numbers. After the initial familiar notions come
>   several others...
>
> - rational
> - algebraic
> - computable
>
> The computable reals are those for which we can compute
>   rational approximations to any desired accuracy, by Turing
>   machine. (A concept used in [computable
>   analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis).)
>   The computable subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are those for which
>   we can compute *yes/no* answers for membership in finite
>   time. For example, all the numbers you mention in the
>   question, such as $\pi$ and $e$, are computable.
>
> - computably enumerable
>
> The c.e. subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are those for which there
>   is a computable enumeration procedure. Equivalently, you
>   can compute the *yes* answers for membership in finite
>   time. The concept of relative (oracle) computability leads to the
>   [hierarchy of Turing
>   degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degrees),
>   which measures the comparative computable complexity of a
>   real.
>
> - arithmetic
>
> A real $x$ is *arithmetic* if it's digits can be defined by
>   a definition involving only quantification over the natural
>   numbers and primitive operations. Equivalently, the
>   arithmetic subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ arise from the
>   computable subsets of $\mathbb{N}^k$ by projection and
>   complement. The [arithmetic
>   hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_hierarchy)
>   breaks naturally into levels, such as $\Sigma^0_n$ and
>   $\Pi^0_n$, corresponding to the logical complexity of these
>   definitions, and these levels are refined by the Turing
>   degrees. For example, the set of Turing machine programs
>   $p$ which compute total functions forms a complete
>   $\Pi^0_2$ set. The relativized notion leads to the arithmetic degrees.
>
> - hyperarithmetic
>
> A real is *hyperarithmetic* if it can be defined by two
>   equivalent definitions, one involving just one universal
>   quantifier over the reals and another having just one
>   existential quantifier over the reals, and otherwise any
>   level of arithmetic quantifiers. This is the same as
>   $\Delta^1_1$. The [hyperarithmetic
>   hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory)
>   is stratified in a hierarchy of length $\omega_1^{CK}$, a
>   lightface version of the Borel hierarchy, in which one uses
>   uniformly computable countable unions and complements. The
>   relativized notion leads to the hyperarithmetic degrees, a
>   hyperarithmetic analogue of the Turing degrees.
>
> - projective
>
> A real is *projective* if it can be defined by a
>   description that quantifies only over the set of real
>   numbers, plus natural number quantification and the
>   primitive operations. The [projective
>   hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy)
>   is stratified by considering the logical complexity of
>   these definitions, with levels $\Sigma^1_n$ and $\Pi^1_n$.
>   For example, the lightface analytic sets are $\Sigma^1_1$
>   and co-analytic is $\Pi^1_1$, with hyperarithmetic being
>   $\Delta^1_1=\Sigma^1_1\cap\Pi^1_1$.
>
> - constructible
>
> A real is *constructible* if it exists in Gödel's
>   [constructible universe
>   $L$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).
>   The concept of relative constructibility gives rise to the
>   constructibility degrees, by which $x\sim y\leftrightarrow
> L[x]=L[y]$, forming a rich hierarchy.
>
> - ordinal-definable
>
> A real (or set) is
>   [*ordinal-definable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable)
>   if there is a definition of it in the language of set
>   theory, using ordinal parameters. For example, the real
>   whose $n^{th}$ binary digit is $1$ just in case
>   $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$ is ordinal definable. The class
>   HOD of all hereditarily ordinal definable sets satisfies
>   ZFC, but can be strictly smaller than the universe of all
>   sets.
>
> - generic
>
> A real is *generic* over $L$ (or some other fixed universe
>   $V$) if it exists in a forcing extension of $L$ (or $V$) by
>   set forcing. Of course, it is relatively consistent with
>   ZFC that every real is generic over $L$, since this is true
>   in $L$ itself, but under some large cardinal axioms, there
>   are reals, such as $0^\sharp$, that cannot be added by
>   forcing over $L$.
>
> The higher levels of these latter hierarchies are further
>   developed and stratified by the enormous variety of models
>   of set theory arising from large cardinals, various inner
>   model constructions, forcing extensions and so on, so that
>   the hierarchy loses its linear nature, becoming instead a
>   dense jungle of various interacting concepts of set theory.

Comment: There are iconic diagrams of the arithmetic hierarchy, which Bjørn and I mentioned, which you can find here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/347375/413. Also, the projective hierarchy continues beyond this with: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projektive_Hierarchie. The entire arithmetic hierarchy lies inside the bottom level of the projective hierarchy. There is a similar hierarchy for the HOD reals, but when it come to genericity, the hierarchy becomes nonlinear and very complicated.

Comment: Sorry, Joel, I was clarifying my question at the same time you were expanding your answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Did you want me to include in my answer some of the graphics to which I link  in my previous comment? Perhaps one can find also even better presentations of those hierarchies.

Comment: In between algebraic and computable reals, we might insert periods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods#Purpose_of_the_classification

Answer (score 5):

There are many such classes of languages depending on the approach you want to use.  Let me focus on just one class: the **hyperarithmetic** (hyperarithmetical?) class, and try to explain why it is a very natural class, by mentioning several equivalent definitions of it:

- "*Computability in a type 2 functional*": a hyperarithmetic set of integers is one that can be computed by a "hyperarithmetical" machine, where a "hyperarithmetical" machine is one that can do everything that a Turing machine can do, but with the additional ability to decide whether a function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ takes a nonzero value, where the function $f$ is *itself* computed by a hyperarithmetical machine.  (In other words, given a hyperarithmetical machine computing $f$, such that $f(n)$ is defined for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a hyperarithmetical machine can compute every $f(n)$ at once and decide whether there is one such that $f(n)\neq 0$, in which case of course it can also trivially find the corresponding $n$; if not every $f(n)$ is defined because the machine computing them does not halt, then the overall call will also not halt).  This definition is recursive, of course, and I didn't formalize it completely, but it still makes sense as the smallest which satisfies the conditions.  In the classical computability literature, this description is called "computability [à la Kleene] in the type 2 functional $\mathbf{E}$", but apparently it is never described in terms of "machines" like I tried to sketch.
- …In practice, a hyperarithmetical machine is one that can compute not only with integers, but also with exact real numbers (i.e., sequences of integers), not *all* real numbers but, precisely, those which are hyperarithmetical.  I think this makes the definition fairly natural.
- …Yet another way of rephrasing the same definition is that a hyperarithmetical machine is one that can compute infinite conjunctions/disjunctions (logical and/or), provided the terms of the conjunction/disjunction are themselves computed hypearithmetically.  This is just a rephrasing of the above, but it provides a link with certain kinds of infinitary logic.
- "*Metarecursion*": a set of integers is hyperarithmetic when it can be computed by a machine much like a register machine, except that the registers are allowed to hold ordinal values, the ordinals ranging up to the Church-Kleene ordinal (=smallest nonrecursive ordinal) $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$, and the machine is allowed to "loop" up to that value (I tried to summarize the idea of such ordinal computations [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108949/various-definitions-of-recursion-from-ordinal-machines), in which terminology I would be speaking of $(\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}},\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}})$-machines).  These machines can compute much more than sets of integers, but those sets of integers which they can compute are precisely the hyperarithmetic ones.
- *The level $\Delta^1_1$ of the [analytical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_hierarchy)* is again the class of hyperarithmetic sets: essentially those sets of integers which can be defined using one second-order quantifier, both in an existential and in a universal manner.  This is an analogue (the so-called "lightface" analogue) of one of the definitions of Borel sets in descriptive set theory.
- *Iterating the Turing jump*: a $0$-machine is just a Turing machine; a $0'$-machine is one that has access to an oracle that can tell it whether a $0$-machine halts; a $0''$-machine is one that has access to an oracle that can tell it whether a $0'$-machine halts; a $0^{(n)}$-machine is what you imagine; a $0^{(\omega)}$-machine (or arithmetical machine) is one that has access to an oracle that can tell it, given $n$, whether a $0^{(n)}$-machine halts; it is possible (although not completely trivial) to iterate this over the recursive ordinals, and hyperarithmetic sets are precisely those which are recognized by a $0^{(\alpha)}$-machine for some recursive ordinal $\alpha$.
- *The sets of integers belonging to the level $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}}$ of Gödel's [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe)* where each level is defined essentially by adding every subset of the previous level that can be defined in it by a first-order formula.  Also, this level $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}}$ is the first one which satisfies a sizable amount of set theory, namely [Kripke-Platek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory).

Since all these definitions conspire to give the same class of hyperarithmetic sets, I think it's fair to say that it's a natural class.  There are plenty of classes both above and below, but I think this one deserves to be better known.

(Also, concerning complexity: there are also plenty of classes between $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$ and $\mathsf{REC}$: there are $\mathsf{ELEMENTARY}$ and $\mathsf{PR}$, but also lots of classes which can be defined between the class $\mathsf{PR}$ of primitive recursive sets/functions and that $\mathsf{REC}$ of recursive sets/functions, and that try to bridge the gap between complexity and computability.  These "subrecursive" hierarchies also deserve to be better known.)

Answer (score 4):

Bjørn mentioned the arithmetical and analytical hierarchies and Joel gave some of the big classifications beyond that, but there's also a theory of the finer gradations ([Turing degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree)).  Moving up levels of the arithmetical and analytical hierarchies is done by iterating the [Turing jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump), to transfinite depth once you are past the arithmetic hierarchy.

The polynomial hierarchy in complexity theory is analogous to the arithmetical hierarchy in logic.